# How to protect data in case of an unauthorized physical access to a server

Tags: server, disk-encryption, physical-access

I have some VMs on a hypervisor. They run linux with full disk encryption.

In case of an unauthorized physical access to a running server, I know that the attacker can extract passcode out of RAM via JTAG to a motherboard or other forensic stuff, and decrypt the disk.

Is there any way, to mitigate the data leak possibility in case of unauthorized physical access to a running server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once someone has unrestricted physical access to your server, they can mount any number of attacks against it to retrieve data. The only solution is to restrict physical access in the first place. Depending on your budget and threat model, this can be done by keeping the server in a locked or even guarded server room where only authorized personnel are allowed to enter, by keycard. The server chassis can be physically locked into the rack, which itself can be bolted down. All of these deterrence measures are designed to reduce the risk of someone getting physical access in the first place.